# Access to the site hosted in a virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iis, owncloud

I have OwnColud on Ubuntu Server. Ubuntu Server is installed on a virtual machine in Windows Server 2012 R2. IIS is installed in Windows and has a site on port 80, and is available over the internet domain name mysite.ru. Also there are the postal service, it is available for mail.mysite.ru. But the site is in Windows OwnCloud and only works in Ubuntu. If OwnCloud worked in Windows would not be a problem, I could place it in a directory, and give it the domain name cloud.mysite.ru. How can I open a site on Linux If it is placed in a virtual machine? I have one outside IP-address, and only port 80

Comment: you can use Application Request Routing / URL rewrite to have IIS act as a reverse proxy fronting your VM. your VM could then be exposed on a local-only network / port but externally the users would be hitting IIS on port 80 with whatever name you wanted.